# micrometer add custom parameter

Tags: newrelic, micrometer

is it possible to register a custom parmeter with micrometer as it is done in new relic? e.g.:   NewRelic.addCustomParameter("customparam", customparam ); I would like to associate a tag to a the current request.

Thanks,
Jorge

Answer (score 1):

Its an old question, I am sure you must have figured it out by now but for others I will add..

If you want to add some extra custom tag to existing micrometer metrics like `http_server_requests_seconds_count` or `http_server_requests_seconds_sum` you need to implement your own `io.micrometer.core.instrument.config.MeterFilter` or override `org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.DefaultWebMvcTagsProvider#getTags`.

You can refer [this project](https://github.com/sumeetmondal/spring-micrometer-metric-grouping) to some samples which I tried some time back